# Is there a way to convert python scripts to an executable/application that can work on BOTH PC and Mac?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, py2app, auto-py-to-exe

Long story short, I created a process automation tool using Python and Tkinter. I used auto-py-to-exe to convert the python scripts into an executable that works like an application on PCs.

My only problem is that the users of the "end application" are using both PCs and Macs.

The executable does not work on Mac, and when I tried using Py2App or PyInstaller to create a Mac application, the scripts did not compile correctly. Are there any other ways to work around this?

Thanks in advance for the help!!!

I tried using Py2App and PyInstaller to create an application that would work on a Mac.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the best way to do this? The python scripts have over 5000 lines of code...I am not sure where the error is when converting it to an app because the executable file works fine on Windows, the script also runs perfectly when I execute it from my Python environment.

Comment: The answer to your question is no.  There is no way to compile a python program to run on windows and mac.

Comment: OK, so in order for this to happen I would need to compile it into an exe for windows and an app for Mac? Do you have a compiler you recommend using for Mac? I tried Py2App and PyInstaller and neither worked... :/

Comment: pyinstaller works on both... so that would be my recommendation.  If it isn't working then find out why it isn't working and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

On the windows platform, you can use some tools such as NSIS.

Comment: Do you mind clarifying a little more? I am unfamiliar with this tool. My current executable file works well on Windows, but I am struggling to convert the python scripts to a usable Mac application.

Comment: On platform MAC,1Install py2app 

pip3 install  py2app 

2. Generate setup.py files

py2applet --make-setup xx.py (files to be packaged)

3. Package the file

python3 setup.py py2app

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).